# Where can I find full documentation to make Authentication Agent for Microsoft Windows?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, login-control

I need to make Authentication Agent for Microsoft Windows to replace the current option to logon Windows (Password, Passcode and image password). I know that there are many companies providing such solutions like Gemalto logon agent and RSA.
Where I can find developers documentation and tutorials for that?

RSA agent:
https://www.rsa.com/en-us/products-services/identity-access-management/securid/authentication-agents/authentication-agent-for-microsoft-windows

SafeNet Authentication Service Agent for Windows Logon: 
http://www2.gemalto.com/sas/resources-downloads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Winlogon and Credential Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)